# An algorithm used for navigation stack

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've read the paper "The Office Marathon".

I couldn't understand whether
"the gradient method(reference [13])" is used for local planning or global planning.
In the paper, global planner uses the method as global planning apparently.
However, in the reference [13], I think it is introduced as local planning.

My question is
the gradient method is used for ... what?

It's originally for local planning, but in the case it's applied to global planner?
If so, will costmap all over the environment be calculated before a robot moves?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37332/an-algorithm-used-for-navigation-stack/) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2012-06-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reference [13] introduces the gradient method as a method that unifies global and local planning.
"The Office Marathon" explains that the gradient method had drawbacks for local planning, so that it was only used for global planning.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1